# Debian 9 Dual boot on Win10 issues

Tags: linux, debian, nvidia, bios

So I have stumbled on plenty of Threads here and over the web. Thing is, dual boot installation on my machine (Alienware R4, 2017) seems to be really really hard - atleast for me.

So I managed to actually install it, but let me list few issues I have now:

1. GRUB **does not detect** my Windows installation (I have Debian on HDD, Win is on SSD)
2. If I want to boot to Windows I have to change **from AHCI setup to RAID on** (which was default before in BIOS, but had to change it so my Debian installation even saw the Hard Drive where I had FREE SPACE to install my Debian)
3. Whenever I try to update my **NVIDIA drivers**, Debian wont load. It opens GRUB, I select Debian, it opens GUI for Login. I enter my credentials, it seems to load, but then it just brings me back to GUI for Login screen (if I purge drivers, it works normally). I need the driver in order ot enable my HDMI output to use dual Monitors (xrandr says HDMI is disconnected).
4. Although I was told that Linux OS were supposed to perform better (faster), I feel like they are slower than Windows 10 - does this mean I screwd up something or my HW is just not that compatible with Linux,since it is a gaming laptop?

Now I know these are several issues, but might be connected to one mistake which some of you guys might help me out with.

**My setup:**

i7-6700HQ

32 GB RAM

Nvidia GTX1070

SSD 512GB (Windows OS)

HDD 1TB (Linux OS)

Killer Wireless Adapter

Comment: I voted close as you have too many questions clubbed into one. Put one issue or question and share what all you have tried about it, then there is a much better chance that somebody might help you.